# Using liquibase for db migration in a docker compose

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, liquibase

I am trying to migrate a database using liquibase. When i ran a docker-compose up, i got the below error. Can you please point me to the right direction?

```text
liquibase_1  | Starting Liquibase at 18:11:09 (version 4.3.1 #26 built at 2021-02-12 17:41+0000)
liquibase_1  | Errors:
liquibase_1  |   The option --url is required.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Liquibase error, that indicates `--url` attribute is missing in the liquibase.properties file. Read more about how to configure liquibase with Docker on the below documents:

- https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-liquibase-and-docker.html
- https://www.liquibase.com/blog/using-liquibase-via-docker